# Python: split a string line

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have wrote the following code to split a line, what I was trying to do is to get the 1.802e+05 and 1.739e+04. I think I can split the line with space, then I can get those values, but what I got so far is only the letter H. Anyone can show me where my bug is?

```
line = 'Htin     1.802e+05 [J kg^-1]    Htout    1.739e+04 [J kg^-1]'
line.split(' ')
print line[0]
```

Answer (score 2):

`line.split()` return the result, which you haven't stored anywhere. So, that line has no effect.
In the next line, `line` is still the string, so line[0] is H

`line = 'Htin     1.802e+05 [J kg^-1]    Htout    1.739e+04 [J kg^-1]'
temp = line.split(' ')
print temp[0]`

Comment: Thank you very mucu. But if the line is sometime like this line = 'Htin 1.802e+05 [J kg^-1] Htout -1.739e+04 [J kg^-1]', some values in line are negative. After splitting, the Htout and -1.739e+04 will combine together, do you have any idea to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I'd skip the `split` and go right for a `re` solution -- e.g if every number you want to extract is in exponential notation,

```
numstrings = re.findall(r'\d\.\d+e[+-]\d+', line)
```

would work.  Just adjust the RE pattern to the forms of numbers you want to extract!

Answer (score 1):

Split doesn't alter line; it returns a list of strings.  But even if it did, line[0] wouldn't give you one of the numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use try/except:

```
>>> line = 'Htin     1.802e+05 [J kg^-1]    Htout    1.739e+04 [J kg^-1]'
>>> result=[]
>>> for e in line.split():
...    try:
...       result.append(float(e))
...    except ValueError:
...       pass
... 
>>> result
[180200.0, 17390.0]
```

Answer (score 1):

`line.split()` will return a result which you are not storing anywhere. Using `line[0]` will give you the character at index `0` in the string `line`.

This should be more what you want:

```
>>> line = 'Htin     1.802e+05 [J kg^-1]    Htout    1.739e+04 [J kg^-1]'
>>> lines = line.split()
>>> lines
['Htin', '1.802e+05', '[J', 'kg^-1]', 'Htout', '1.739e+04', '[J', 'kg^-1]']
>>> lines[1]
'1.802e+05'
>>> lines[5]
'1.739e+04'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

line = 'Htin     1.802e+05 [J kg^-1]    Htout    1.739e+04 [J kg^-1]'
a=line.split()
for x in a:
    if re.findall("[0-9][0-9]",x):
        print (x)
```

Output:

```
>>> 
1.802e+05
1.739e+04
>>>
```

`re` module for search what you want.

Comment: As I've already said, it doesn't make any sense to use `split()` if you're using `re.findall()`; please see @Alex Martelli's answer for how to correctly use the `re` module

Comment: @howaboutNO My downvote has nothing to do with others; it's not about correct or not; you can write 100 print statements to print number 1 to 100 and claim it's as correct as using a for loop, that's similar to what this answer does